# Get index of selected DOM element return -1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I bind album_item for click event, and I want to get box's index. But I got -1.

**HTML**

```
<div id="album_item">
    <div class="box box_album_item">
        <div class="album_item">a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box box_album_item">
        <div class="album_item">b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box box_album_item">
        <div class="album_item">c</div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    $(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.album_item', function () {
            alert($(this).find('.box_album_item').index());
        });
    });
```

Comment: There are no `.box_album_item`s within `.album_item`, you have the relationship backward.

Comment: It's also worth reading [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/index/) which tells you exactly when and why `index` would return -1.

Comment: Anyone care to state why they are downvoting?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select an element that does not exist:

The `find()` function searches for children of the given element, in this case `.album_item`. So, `.album_item` down not have any children elements, that's why it's index is -1

Instead, you must use `closest()` function in order to search upwards the DOM tree:

```
$(document).on('click', '.album_item', function () {

        alert($(this).closest('.box_album_item').index());

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
alert($(this).closest('.box_album_item').index());
```

1. `.find()` goes inside of the element to the children.
2. `.closest()` traverses upwards to the parents.

so in your case `.box_album_item` is the parent, so `.closest()` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($(this).closest('.box_album_item').index());
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/f3okr0ba/1/**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '#album_item', function () {
```

use id instead class